# MYSQL printing a database record array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, function

```
function CHECKPENDINGORDERS($con, $oc, $pos){
    if(is_resource($con)){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM eats_orders WHERE school_code = '$oc' AND order_status = '$pos'";
        $sqlresult = mysql_query($sql);
        #$pendingorderrow = mysql_fetch_array($sqlresult);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlresult)){
            $a[] = $row;
            return $a;
        }

    }
}


$checkpendingorders =  CHECKPENDINGORDERS(MYSQL_LINK, $ordercode, $pendingorderstatus);

print_r($checkpendingorders);
```

I have the function above me to retrieve db records to and print it out by calling the function. But it is only printing 1 recording but I have multiple records with same ordercode and pendingorderstatus.

Answer (score 2):

### You need to return your `$a` at the end

```
<?php
function CHECKPENDINGORDERS($con, $oc, $pos){
    if(is_resource($con)){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM eats_orders WHERE school_code = '$oc' AND order_status = '$pos'";
        $sqlresult = mysql_query($sql);
        #$pendingorderrow = mysql_fetch_array($sqlresult);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlresult)){
            $a[] = $row;
            //return $a; //<---- Not here
        }

    }
    return $a; //<----- Here
}
```

That is because... You are getting a single row is since you are returning the `$a` in the first iteration itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your `return` statement outside of your loop. Once that `return` statement is reached your function call ends thus terminating your loop.

```
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlresult)){
        $a[] = $row;
    }
    return $a;
```

To further improve upon your function, your function will throw a `E_NOTICE` error because you  are not defining `$a` before using it. To solve this just define `$a` to be an empty string at the top of your function. You can also move the `return` statement to the end of the array so your function always returns an array, even if it is empty.

```
function CHECKPENDINGORDERS($con, $oc, $pos){
    $a = array();
    if(is_resource($con)){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM eats_orders WHERE school_code = '$oc' AND order_status = '$pos'";
        $sqlresult = mysql_query($sql);
        #$pendingorderrow = mysql_fetch_array($sqlresult);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlresult)){
            $a[] = $row;
        }
    }
    return $a;
}
```